# Proof about Harmonic function

Tags: complex-analysis

I have this exercise, which our instructor refused to give us the solution even after submitting the homework. It's the second implication of question (2) which was the most difficult, and I was not able to prove.

1) Let $f:\mathbb{C}\to \mathbb{C}$, be a $C^2$ function. Prove that $f$ is harmonic if and only if $\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial z\partial\bar{z}}=0.$

By the definition, we know that $f$ is harmonic if $\dfrac{\partial ^2 f}{\partial x^2}+\dfrac{\partial ^2 f}{\partial y^2}=0$.

But, using $\dfrac{\partial}{\partial z}=\dfrac{1}{2}\bigg(\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x}+\dfrac{1}{i}\dfrac{\partial }{\partial y}\bigg)$ and  $\dfrac{\partial}{\partial \bar{z}}=\dfrac{1}{2}\bigg(\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x}-\dfrac{1}{i}\dfrac{\partial }{\partial y}\bigg)$, we will get that $$\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial z\partial\bar{z}}=\dfrac{1}{4}\bigg(\dfrac{\partial ^2 f}{\partial x^2}+\dfrac{\partial ^2 f}{\partial y^2}\bigg),$$
which shows that $f$ is harmonic if and only if $\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial z\partial\bar{z}}=0.$

2) Prove that a polynomial $P(x,y)$ is harmonic if and only if there exist two polynomials $U$ and $V$ such that $$P(x,y)=U(z)+V(\bar{z}).$$

$\circ$ If $P(x,y)=U(z)+V(\bar{z}),$ then $\dfrac{\partial P}{\partial z\partial\bar{z}}=\dfrac{\partial }{\partial z\partial\bar{z}}\big(U(z)+V(\bar{z})\big)=\dfrac{\partial }{\partial z\partial\bar{z}} U(z)+\dfrac{\partial }{\partial z\partial\bar{z}} V(\bar{z})=0+0=0$. So, by (1), $P$ is harmonic.

$\circ$ Suppose that $P$ is harmonic. By (1), $\dfrac{\partial P}{\partial z\partial \bar{z}}=0 $. By integrating with respect to $\bar{z}$, we get that $$\dfrac{\partial P}{\partial z}=\text{constant of}\ \bar{z}=V(\bar{z})...$$
 I tried by integrating with respect to $z$ and $\bar{z}$ but I think that will not work.

Any idea? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $x = \frac{z+\bar{z}}{2}$ and $y = \frac{z-\bar{z}}{2i}$, we can express $P$ as a polynomial in the variables $z$ and $\bar{z}$, so that
$$ P(z,\bar{z}) = \sum\limits_{m,n\ge 0}{c_{mn}z^m(\bar{z})^n} $$
for some coefficients $c_{mn}\in\mathbb{C}$. We can split this sum into the terms where the power of $\bar{z}$ is zero, terms where the power of $z$ is zero, and terms where the power of both terms is at least one. That is, we can write
$$ P(z,\bar{z}) = \sum\limits_{m\ge 0}{a_mz^m} + \sum\limits_{n\ge 1}{b_n(\bar{z})^n} + \sum\limits_{m,n\ge 1}{c_{mn}z^m(\bar{z})^n} $$
for $a_m := c_{m0}$ and $b_n := c_{0n}$. It suffices to show that $c_{mn} = 0$ if $m\ge 1$ and $n\ge 1$. Now
$$\frac{\partial P}{\partial z} = \sum\limits_{m\ge 0}{ma_mz^{m-1}} + \sum\limits_{m,n\ge 1}{mc_{mn}z^{m-1}(\bar{z})^n} $$
and
$$\frac{\partial^2P}{\partial\bar{z}\partial z} = \sum\limits_{m,n\ge 1}{mnc_{mn}z^{m-1}(\bar{z})^{n-1}}. $$
Hence, if $P$ is harmonic, then $\frac{\partial^2P}{\partial\bar{z}\partial z} = 0$, so every coefficient on the RHS must be zero. Thus, $mnc_{mn} = 0$ for all $m\ge 1$ and $n\ge 1$, which implies that $c_{mn} = 0$ for all $m\ge 1$ and $n\ge 1$.

Thus, we have $P(z,\bar{z}) = U(z) + V(\bar{z})$, for $U(z) = \sum\limits_{m\ge 0}{a_mz^m}$ and $V(\bar{z}) = \sum\limits_{n\ge 1}{b_n(\bar{z})^n}$.